# How to enable TypeScript intellisense in VSCode for a codebase in JavaScript when doing module augmentation for a third-party library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, material-ui

In a standard `create-react-app` configuration, there’s a third-party component that I can import when needed:

```js
import { Button } from '@mui/material'

// […]
<Button variant="|"></Button>
```

The library is fully-typed, so hitting `Ctrl`+`Space` in VSCode when the cursor is at `|` will show me a list of possible string variants that I can use. I could add another variant by creating a local component that wraps the `@mui/material/Button`:

```js
// LocalComponent.js
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'

// Do something to actually add a variant called `new`.

export const LocalComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Button ref={ref} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  )
})
```

```js
// LocalComponent.d.ts
import type { ButtonProps } from '@mui/material'

interface Props extends ButtonProps {
  /** @default 'text' */
  variant?: 'text' | 'outlined' | 'contained' | 'new'
}

export declare function LocalComponent(props: Props): React.FunctionComponent
```

If I import `LocalComponent`, I can get intellisense for the new variant, as well as the original `Button`’s props. The library also has a feature that allows me to create new variants without having to wrap the library’s components, but I’m having problems with intellisense when I use it—even though the `new` variant is implemented, I see only the original variants. The library exposes an interface specifically for module augmentation, so I should be doing something like this:

```ts
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    new: true;
  }
}
```

`ButtonPropsVariantOverrides` is supposed to be merged with the `variant` property of the interface that defines all props for the `Button`, essentially turning it into `variant?: 'text' | 'outlined' | 'contained' | 'new'`, but it seems that TypeScript doesn’t see this module augmentation. I tried the following setup:

```json
// jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types", "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Not sure if `typeRoots` does anything in `jsconfig`—it’s not listed as an available option of `compilerOptions`, but since `jsconfig` is almost `tsconfig`, I tried it anyway.

```
.
├── src/
│   └── types/
│       └── @mui/
│           └── material/
│               └── Button/
│                   └── index.d.ts // Contains the module augmentation from above.
└── jsconfig.json
```

As well as this one:

```
.
├── src/
│   └── types/
│       └── index.d.ts // Contains the module augmentation from above.
└── jsonfig.json
```

I also made sure to restart the TS server every time I changed something. Where to put module augmentations in general? Is there anything wrong with how I set up `jsconfig.json`? [Here’s a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-worker-ccsro?file=/src/App.js) of what I’ve just described.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30656

Comment: I'm not well-versed in typescript but putting it in `LocalComponent.d.ts` seems to solve the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dan-sk4wf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when a file with module augmentation doesn’t have `import`/`export` statements, you’re defining an [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules)—a shape that does not have an implementation—that you have to import manually where needed. To augment a module and make it globally available, the declaration file should have an `import` or `export` statement.

What’s bizarre is that the only thing that matters is for the declaration file to be a module with at least one `import`/`export` statement, which could be absolutely anything—if I’m augmenting `@mui/material/Button`, I don’t have to `import '@mui/material/Button'` specifically, I could write some useless arbitrary export, like `export default true`, and TypeScript would recognize the file anyway.

I did a quick test on CodeSandbox to see if the same applies to TypeScript projects—[it seemingly does](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-tereshkova-4p5sx?file=/src/App.tsx). It worked on CodeSandbox without the `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig.json`, but add it in case of problems.

> Where to put module augmentations in general? Is there anything wrong with how I set up `jsconfig.json`?

Module augmentation can be in any folder you like, but that directory *(or its ancestor)* should be in the `jsconfig`’s `include` property, and if its ancestor has already been added to `include`, there’s no need to list the directory with types separately. Although unnecessary, you might want to separate augmented packages into folders containing `index.d.ts`—do not name the declaration files differently, or TypeScript will ignore them. Using my question as an example, one option is to put the module augmentation into `./src/types/@mui/Button/index.d.ts`. Lastly, the `typeRoots` property, indeed, does nothing when added to `jsconfig.json`, so there’s no need to use it.

Comment: adding the import on top helped: import Button from '@mui/material/Button'. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

is better if you use `tsconfig.json`

if you use tsconfig and JSDoc [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqqst.png)

your code can look like that

there are some properties of the tsconfig.json that we need to focus on. and the must important is `baseUrl` it is used for

> Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names.

so take express for example

```
import express from "express";
```

with **baseUrl** we tell typescript where to look for them express types the *tsc* will prefix the imports paths like so

```
import express from "./node_modules/express";
```

per say... I choose express for a reason because quite often there are packages which does not includes them types, but there is a huge community that can have done them for us, to use them we need to import them separately

```
$ npm i -D @types/express
```

there will be some times in which you'll need to override them types to do so you need to let tsc where to look for them overrides with `paths` to do it properly you need to create a dir at the root of yow project with name types

```
project
--node_modules
--src
--types
--tsconfig.json
```

something important to mention is that inside of your types dir you need to create a dir with the same identifier as the one used in the import statement to keep with our example it will look like this

```
project
--node_modules
--src
--types
----express
------index.d.ts
--tsconfig.json
```

and its proper file needs to be call `index.d.ts`

lets add a new property to the request method of express `userIp` the new property will refer to the client ip address so it needs to be a string and it needs to be inside the req property
so let's override it

```
/**
 * Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module.
 */
declare function e (): core.Express;

declare namespace e {
    interface Request<P = EnetoParams, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> {
        /** ip del usuario que solicito la peticion */
        userIp: string;
    }
}
export = e;
```

now tell *tsc* where to find it. `paths` is used for it

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl":"./node_modules",
      "paths": {
         "express":["./@types/express/index.d.ts","../types/express/index.d.ts"]
      }
   }
}
```

the format is

```
"paths": {
   "name used in the import statement":[
      "path to the original definitions",
      "path to the override",
       "if any other exists"
   ]
}
```

if you do not want to do it for all them changes and stuff you can use wild cards

```
"paths": {
      "*": ["./*/index.d.ts", "./*/types.d.ts", "./*/types", "./@types/index.d.ts","./@types/types.d.ts"]
    }
```

we start them paths with `./` because our baseUrl is `./node_modules` now tell the *tsc* where to find our own types or definitions

```
{
  // baseUrl is ./node_modues thats why we need to get out of that dir and get inside types dir
  "typeRoots": ["../types/index.d.ts"]
}
```

the index.d.ts

```
declare module "my-package-name" {
  interface SomeObj {
     prop1: string;
     prop2: string;
  }

}
```

the way of using it in your code like so

```
import { SomeObj } from "my-package-name";

const myVar: SomeObj = {};
```